# Seeking a word or term for being sadistically pedantic or law enforcing

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

It’s a term I heard 10+ years ago and it slipped my mind. It’s either a word (possibly a compound word) or maybe two-word term (it may even be a longer phrase but I doubt it) for ruthlessly following the rules or enforcing the law with sinister, sadistic or nefarious intent.

Please note that it is NOT Draconianism.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a sample sentence showing where the word you're looking for would go.

Comment: Seems to be classic machiavellianism, but that's a psychological term. (need for control, harsh management tactics...). https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/18398/is-a-concept-of-machiavellianism-useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machiavellianism#Game_theory

Comment: Could you mean Manichean or Procrustean?

Answer (score 1):

A person who behaves as you describe may be called a **martinet**. Here is the definition of the word in [Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/martinet) (2003):

> **martinet** *n* **1 :** a strict disciplinarian {The prison's warden was a cruel *martinet*} **2 :** a person who stresses a rigid adherence to the details of forms and methods {a *martinet* in conducting meetings of the society, he never tolerated any sign of levity or indecorum —D. J. Boorstin}

Elsewhere on its website, in an article titled "[10 Words That Prove Fame Isn't Everything](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/a-famous-name-isnt-always-a-good-thing/burke)," Merriam-Webster reports that the word refers to a seventeenth-century French military man named Jean Martinet:

> **Martinet**
>
> **Definition:** one who lays stress on a rigid adherence to the details of forms and methods
>
> It takes a special kind of person to be so despised by one’s subordinates that one’s name becomes synonymous with “nitpicking-meanie.” Such a person was Jean Martinet. In the 1660s King Louis XIV appointed Martinet to be in charge of training his infantry, and the drillmaster set to his task with gusto, insisting on rigid adherence to form and ruthlessly punishing offenders. The measure of his success depends somewhat on the point of view you take; although he did manage to turn his charges into a competent fighting brigade, they ended up killing him during the siege of Duisburg in 1672. *Martinet* has been used to mean "strict disciplinarian" since the 1730s.
>
> [Cited example:] "Papa is such a martinet. He declares that I shall never marry a man who has not some regular business." —Thomas Masson, *Munsey's Magazine*, January, 1910

According to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martinet) for the word, a *martinet* may also refer to a small, many-tailed flail, whip, or scourge:

> A martinet is a short, scourge-like (multi-tail) type of whip made of a wooden handle of about 25 cm (10 inches) in length and about 10 lashes of equal, relatively short length. The lashes are usually made of leather, but sometimes soap-stiffened cords are used in place of leather. It is a traditional instrument of physical punishment in France and other European countries. In French, it also refers to a similar dusting implement; the type for chastisement was also known as *fouet d'enfant*, meaning *child's whip*.
>
> ...
>
> In English, the term *martinet* usually refers not to the whip, but to those who might use it—those who demand strict adherence to set rules and mete out punishment for failing to follow them. This sense of the word reputedly comes from Jean Martinet, Inspector General of the army of Louis XIV, and thus, etymologically, only by accident relates to the earlier sense.

Whether or not this is the term you had in mind, a **martinet** is certainly a ruthless enforcer of harsh discipline upon the slightest pretext offered by an infraction committed against arbitrary and often picayune rules.

Comment: This addresses the *pedantic* and *law enforcing* aspects very well. Does *martinet* also carry the connotation of being (intentionally) *sadistic*, as opposed to 'merely' displaying OCD?

Comment: @Lawrence: To judge from the photo of the _martinet_ in the Wikipedia article that I link to in my answer, sadism is fairly close to the surface of _martinet_ in its "application of punishment" aspect.  The Merriam-Webster article that I link to notes that Jean Martinet's men hated him so much that, during a siege that he was overseeing, they conspired (successfully) to assassinate him. Still, I think it would be possible to be a martinet without being, in a clinical sense, a sadist.

Comment: Yes, that argument is plausible. The military is almost discipline personified, but most don't assassinate their commanding officers or instructors.

Answer (score 0):

[Officious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/officious)

> - Assertive of authority in a domineering way, especially with regard to trivial matters.
> - Intrusively enthusiastic in offering help or advice; interfering.

This word is often used for people who are on a power trip, who like to throw their weight around enforcing (and sometimes overstepping) their authority.